# Is there a Visual Studio 2010 extension that duplicates Resharper's To-do explorer in C++ Projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I like to use Resharper's To-do explorer in C# projects. I'm looking for something with similar functionality for C++ projects in Visual Studio 2010. Specifically, I like the ability to define different types of to-do tags and be able to filter and sort the to-do items within Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I handle TODO comments in VisualStudio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823875/how-do-i-handle-todo-comments-in-visualstudio-2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your tokens in Options window `Tools->Options->Environment-> Task List`. Some tokens, like *TODO, HACK* already there.

Open the *Task List* view where you can browse and manage your tasks.

You might need to make sure that `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->Enumerate Comment Tasks` is set to TRUE.

Task List in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/170k1bbs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! This doesn't quite duplicate Resharper's to-do explorer (with regex matching for todo items) but it's basically what I was looking for.